# Lenovo flex 2-15 doesn't turn off

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, lenovo

i installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my lenovo laptop as dual boot but every time i try to shut  down the PC it starts again after 5 seconds or so and i have to press the power button to turn it off

I hope anyone can help me?

Edit

I've noticed that it happens only when i'm not connected to the power adapter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a brand new Lenovo Flex 2 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  After a lot of trial and error (online research, Lubuntu 14.10 live CD, installed Windows 7, updated BIOS) I fixed it by disabling xHCI on the BIOS.  Hope it works for you.